# Filter items on date (Django)

Tags: django

I make a simple todo list. First, I display a list of all dates on which items have been added.

- views.py

  ```
  def allDates(request):
      date = Todo.objects.extra(select={'custom_dt': 'strftime("%d-%m-%Y", "created_at")'}).values_list('custom_dt', flat=True).order_by('-custom_dt').distinct() # display all dates

      return render(request, 'todo/alldates.html', {'date':date})
  ```
- alldates.html

  ```
  {% for dat in date %}
      <a href="{% url 'detaildate' %}"><h1>{{ dat }}</h1></a> # link to see items added to this date
  {% endfor %}
  ```

[image]

After I try to create a method that filters the items by date I clicked on

- views.py (detaildate)

  ```
  def detailDate(request):
     detail = Todo.objects.order_by('-created_at')
     return render(request, 'todo/detaildate.html', {'detail':detail})
  ```

I have this result, display all items, but i need only from date I link

[image]

How I can display - filter items by date in link ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use:

`def detailDate(request, date):
   detail = Todo.objects.filter(created_at=date)
   return render(request, 'todo/detaildate.html', {'detail':detail})`

You want to filter objects not ordering them.

Comment: I have - detailDate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date'

Answer (score 0):

```
detail = Todo.objects.order_by('-created_at')
return render(request, 'todo/detaildate.html', {'detail':detail})
```

By doing this you are passing todo objects to the django templates. If you only want the date to be displayed in templates then you have to loop through the objects and only show the date by doing these in the detaildate.html

```
{% for det in detail %}
    {{det.created_at}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you are trying to filter the todo by date then you have to query it by

```
todos = Todo.objects.filter(created_date=date)
```

Comment: I have - detailDate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date'

Comment: `def detailDate(request, date):
  detail = Todo.objects.filter(created_date=date)
  return render(request, 'todo/detaildate.html', {'detail':detail})` date missing

Comment: If you are passing date like this then you have to append it in URLs. Otherwise, you can pass date as a request parameter. So you can get it within the request as request.GET.get('date') if it is a get request.    so the function would be like . def detailDate(request):                                              date=request.GET.get('date')                                                                         detail = Todo.objects.filter(created_date=date)                                                                     return render(request, 'todo/detaildate.html', {'detail':detail})